# I have been trying to fetch data from XMLRPC client

Tags: javascript, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

This is a piece of code I wrote. I have trouble accessing data from Promise for later purposes.

```
function forgotPassword(params) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return client.methodCall('forgotPassword', params, function (error, value) {
      if (error === null) {
        if (value === true) {
          console.log('Password Sent!!');
          //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
          return resolve('Password Sent!!');
        }
        else {
          console.log('User Not Found!!');
          //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
          return resolve('User Not Found!!');
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error while doing the Operation!!');
        //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: what is data here ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DankDizaster The data here is whether the password is sent to the respective mail id or no. I have returned a specific value to the function. I'm trying to store the value from Promise for later purposes but I'm not able to.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the docs on [Async Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_functio) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

In this case you can do a few things

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return client.methodCall('forgotPassword', params, function (error, value) {
      if (error === null) {
        if (value === true) {
          console.log('Password Sent!!');
          //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
          return resolve('Password Sent!!');
        }
        else {
          console.log('User Not Found!!');
          //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
          return resolve('User Not Found!!');
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error while doing the Operation!!');
        //subpy.kill('SIGINT');
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  })
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(rej => console.log(rej));
```

The `then` will be called if the `resolve` is called.

The `catch` will be called if there is an `error` or `reject` is called.

Another way is to use `await` inside a `async` function to wait until you get a result from the promise object

```
function myPromiseFunction(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {.....
}

async function myfunction() {
  try {
      var res = await myPromiseFunction(); // waits until result from promise
      console.log(res);
  } catch (error){
      console.log(error);
  }
  
}

myfunction();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It really helped me.